# Korean Texting Culture

Tags: meaning

If someone says "Thank you ㅠㅠ" to the person who tells that person to sleep and eat well on the weekend, what does that mean? I thought people use ㅋㅋㅋ after saying thank you

Comment: Ah, `ㅋㅋㅋ` is like `lol`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ㅠㅠ is a crying face! Like ' ;-; ' or ' ;.; ' if you're familiar with those.
It was probably added as a way to show they are touched by your 'go to sleep and rest' sentiment :]

Comment: ;-( or  would be better crying face, I think.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me!